# cout not recognized but have correct include directories?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, icc

I am using Intel Compiler on Linux, with Eclipse and for the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "test";
}
```

cout is not recognised.

If I go to project properties and then "C/C++ General" and then "Paths and Symbols" I have:

> /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/compiler/include
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.7
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.7/backward
>
> /usr/local/include
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed
>
> /usr/include
>
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu

could some one please help? thanks

EDIT command line used in Eclipse:

> icpc -MMD -MP -MF"Main.d" -MT"Main.d" -c -o "Main.o" "../Main.cpp"

Exact error message:

> catastrophic error: cannot open source file "bits/c++config.h"

Comment: Your compiler is probably not properly installed/configured.

Comment: What's the exact error message, and what is the exact command line being run? Does it work when you try to compile on the command line?

Comment: @Synxis I followed the intel directions, installing the compiler via "Add new software" and it all went through ok. When I created my project I used an Intel toolchain which was available (version 13 I believe). If I do icc --version it gives the correct version number?

Comment: @Mat "symbol 'cout' could not be resolved". How can I find out the exact command line being ran?

Comment: Can you retrieve the command line generated by Eclipse for the compilation ?

Comment: icpc -MMD -MP -MF"Main.d" -MT"Main.d" -c -o "Main.o" "../Main.cpp"

catastrophic error: cannot open source file "bits/c++config.h"

Comment: The error isnt the same. I have found the path for bits/c++config.h, added this and I still get an error. The error says "/usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream(39): catostrophic error: cannot open source file bits/c++config.h"

Comment: Googling your problem showed other people solve it by closing the project and reopening it.

Comment: @DrewDormann googling my problem didn't solve it.... manually looking for c++config.h in the linux subsystem and adding that reference did though....